# NodeJS profiling - what is "nonexistent_symbol"?

Tags: javascript, node.js, profiling

When running a profiling session I got the following as the top result:

```
[JavaScript]:
   ticks  total  nonlib   name
  11588   66.1%   66.1%  Handler: symbol("nonexistent_symbol" hash 157aee38)
```

What does "nonexistent_symbol" actually mean? Is there any way to get more details on what code is actually running? I haven't been able to find a shred of documentation about this.